# Retrieve Emails From Certain Date

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to retrieve emails > than 12/1/2020 but get a `ValueError`. I tried adding `.replace(microseconds=0)` to `str(message.ReceivedTime)` but still getting this error.

error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SLID/PycharmProjects/PPC_COASplitter/PPC_Ack.py", line 178, in <module>
    get_url = readEmail()
  File "C:/Users/zSLID/PycharmProjects/PPC_COASplitter/PPC_Ack.py", line 144, in readEmail
    if str(message.ReceivedTime) >= '2020-12-1 00:00:00' and 'P1 Cust ID 111111 File ID' in message.Subject:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999
```

code

```
def readEmail():

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    folder = outlook.Folders.Item('SharedMailbox, PPC-Investigation')
    inbox = folder.Folders.Item('Inbox')

    messages = inbox.Items
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

    for message in messages:
        
        if str(message.ReceivedTime) >= '2020-12-1 00:00:00' and 'P1 Cust ID 111111 File ID' in message.Subject:
            print("")
            print('Received from: ',message.Sender)
            print("To: ", message.To)
            print("Subject: ", message.Subject)
            print("Received: ", message.ReceivedTime)
            print("Message: ", message.Body)
            get_url = re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', message.Body)[2].strip('>')

            return get_url
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace? I don't think the relevant code is in your current question.

Comment: Hi, i edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are comparing DateTime value with a string. Convert the string to a date-time value.

Secondly, never loop through all items in a folder, use [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) instead (returns a restricted `Items` collection):

```
messages = messages.Restrict("[Received] >= '1/12/2020 0:00am' ")
```